# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been bloked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/ws' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: are you using express js?

Comment: I got this error last week. I solved the problem by adding the following phrase to the package.json.  "proxy": "YourAPIUrl". Please try it and return back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

When invoking an `XMLHttpRequest`, the browser makes a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and checks for an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to determine whether the request should be allowed. You should edit your server code to send that header with a value that allows the domain of your client (or just `*` to allow CORS requests from any origin). For example, if using a Node server with Express, you could do `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')`